# How to store Screen Command output (x amount of seconds) into a file

Tags: macos

I understand that in order to save a screen command you can do:

```
screen /dev/tty.usbserial-DA01G657 57600
```

and then Ctrl+a+H and it stores it.

I am looking for a way of storing the output into a file but having a time limit on the data.

for example:

I start reading from that port for 1 minute and record that data into a file. But JUST for that 1 minute.

It could be wither by time or by quantity of characters stored.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably wouldn't use `screen` for this. If your goal is simply to record `X` minutes of serial port data to a file, how about:

```
stty -F /dev/tty.usbserial-DA01G657 speed 57600
timeout 60 cat /dev/tty.usbserial-DA01G657 > output.txt
```

Comment: When I try it on my Mac it says "-F is not valid" you know why?

Comment: If you're using MacOS, why did you tag your question `linux`?  Commands under MacOS won't necessarily support the same flags as their Linux equivalents. Check the `stty` man page for an appropriate alternative.